# Spring Integration 5.1 - integration flow test - dsl

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I have set up a simple Spring Integration flow which is composed of such steps:

1. poll a rest api periodically then
2. do some processing on the payload
3. and land it on a Kafka topic.

Please observe the code below:

```
@Component
public class MyIntegrationFlow extends IntegrationFlowAdapter {
    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return from(() -> List.of("pathVariable1", "pathVariable2"), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .split()
                .handle(httpRequest(), c -> c.advice(new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice()))
                .transform(Tranformers.fromJson(Foo.class))
                .filter(payload -> payload.isValid())
                .log()
                .transform(Tranformers.toJson())
                .channel(Source.OUTPUT); // output channel for kafka topic
    }

    private HttpMessageHandlerSpec httpRequest() {
        return Http.outboundGateway("http://somehost:8080/{pathVariable}")
                .httpMethod(GET)
                .uriVariable("pathVariable", Message::getPayload)
                .expectedResponseType(String.class);
    }
}
```

This works brilliantly, however, I am struggling to come up with some good tests.

- How am I supposed to mock the external REST API?
- How am I supposed to test that the retry policy does kick in and the desired number of http requests are made?
- How do I change the `MessageSource` of the flow (list of path vars) that is polled periodically?
- How do I check if the payload has successfully made it to the Kafka topic?

Answer (score 0):

Too much questions and some of them requires too broad explanation. Anyway I think you can start from Spring Integration Testing Framework and its [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#testing).

1. > How am I supposed to mock the external REST API?

I think you can just consider to use a Mock MVC from Spring Framework and its `MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory` to inject into the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` based on the `HttpMessageHandlerSpec`.

2. > retry policy does kick

Well, I guess the same mocked MVC endpoint can verify how many times it has been called and fail for first several times to initiate that retry.

3. > How do I change the MessageSource

This is exactly a part of Spring Integration Testing Framework with its `MockIntegration.mockMessageSource()` and `MockIntegrationContext`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#mockintegration

4. > made it to the Kafka topic?

Or you the mentioned `MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler()`  to verify that endpoint for Kafka is called. Or use an `Embedded Kafka` from Spring Kafka project: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#embedded-kafka-annotation